# Run all scripts in a directory with phantomjs

Tags: phantomjs

Using phantomjs, how to run all scripts within a directory?

Ex: I have 3 tests in c:\tests folder.

\firsttest.js

\secondtest.js

\thirdtest.js

I have tried below, but didn't work

phantomjs tests/

phantomjs tests/*

Can someone let me know how to achieve this?

Thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37420286/make-phantomjs-run-all-js-files-in-the-current-directory/37420608

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS itself is not a test framework , neither a testing library : it provides scripted headless testing of web applications.

There are no options in phantomjs that allow you to run a set of scripts ; but there are some popular projects which are built on top of PhantomJS to provide convenient high-level functionality for testing purposes. For example, [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/).

As said [here](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/testing.html#arguments),

> It will recursively scan any passed directory to search for *.js or
>   *.coffee files and add them to the stack.

A gist is also available [here](https://gist.github.com/n1k0/3813361).