# Make phantomjs run all '*.js' files in the current directory

Tags: bash, phantomjs, test-runner

I want to write a script to call `phantomjs` on a bunch of test scripts in a directory.
This script runs the first test and then exits.

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.js' -type f -exec phantomjs {} +
```

Executing a similar command with `echo`, like

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.js' -type f -exec echo {} +
```

prints (as expected) all the filenames in the directory.

How can I make phantomjs run all `.js` files in the current directory? Is this a bash problem or a phantomjs problem?

Comment: Is it important to run a single `phantomjs` process for all the files at once? If not, then you can replace `+` with `\;` to run one `phantomjs` for each file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK phantomjs will only support one file at the time. You need to tell `find` to call phantomjs for each found file:

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.js' -type f -exec phantomjs {} ';'
```

You can also use:

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in *.js; do
  [ -f "$file" ] || continue
  phantomjs "$file"
done
```